# Regex replace all tags by one

Tags: java, regex, xml, java-8

I'm always struggling with Regex, I want to replace multiple tags in my xml by one.

The content of each tag of `<b>` is dynamic, and it could include another `tags`

So having

```
   <a>
     <c>hi</c>
     <b>hello1</b>
     <b><f>bla</f></b>
     <b>hello3</b>
     <b>hello4</b>
   </a>
```

I want to replace all `<b>` tags by just one tag of mine `<b>world</b>`and left `<c>` as it is.

```
    <a>
     <c>hi</c>
     <b>world</b>
   </a>
```

Any idea how? It's better use an XML Parser instead?

Regards.

Comment: Don't struggle with regex, this is not a job for regular expressions. See the classic post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. It is much better to use XSLT or XQuery for this kind of job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT solution:

```
<xsl:template match="/a">
  <a>
    <xsl:copy-of select="c"/>
    <b>world</b>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<a>.*<\/a>` pattern with dot all option (flag s) and replace by something like `<a><b>world</b></a>`

or replace `<b>.*<\/b>` by `<b>world</b>`

see : https://regex101.com/r/fhdwbz/4

Comment: Thanks but it does not cover my use case. Change the modification of my  question.

Comment: Please give more exemples it's not clear

Comment: I update the question, it should be more clear now. That example is just what I want to achieve ;)

Comment: So my second example does the job :  https://regex101.com/r/fhdwbz/4